# Can my Facelets converter depend on a `ui:repeat` loop var?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

The following doesn't work as I'd hoped:

```
<ul>
    <ui:repeat var="i" value="#{fn:split('1,2,3,4', ',')}">
        <li>
            <h:outputText value="1.2345">
                <f:convertNumber
                        minFractionDigits="#{i}"
                        maxFractionDigits="#{i}" />
            </h:outputText>
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

I was hoping to see:

> - 1.2
> - 1.23
> - 1.234
> - 1.2345

Instead I see:

> - 1
> - 1
> - 1
> - 1

What am I missing? My guess is that the converter is initialised when the Facelet is initially loaded, before the run-time looping occurs. Is there a way around this?

My real use-case involves a RichFaces `rich:dataTable` component instead of a `ui:repeat`, but the gist is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not to work indeed. Even if you use `<h:outputText value="#{1.2345}">`, which is more correct.

I guess, if you need this, you will have to prepare the output in the managed bean.